# Laravel - PopularityCount attribute - Order By

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a problem in ordering/sorting results. 
Basically I have **posts** table, and I count **popularity_count** based on how many comments and likes it have. The thing is that I also paginate results. So
when I use something like this

```
$Posts->paginate(5);
$Posts->sortBy('popularity_count');
$Posts->get();
```

It sorts only for specific page, so eg. page 1 has results with popularity count like: 6,5,4,3,2, and second page has 10,7,5,2,1. As you can see there is posts with popularity **10** and it should be as the first result on the first page.

When I try to use

```
 $Posts->orderBy('popularity_count')
```

it doesn't work as I don't have column in my database like this. Is there any possibility to achieve what I want without using RAW selects and joins? I have more custom Attributes on my Model.

Thanks!

edit:

```
`public function getPopularityCountAttribute(){

    $comments = $this->getRelation('commentsCount');

    $likes = $this->getRelation('likesCount');


    $comments = ($comments) ? (int) $comments->comments_count : 0;

    $likes = ($likes) ? (int) $likes->likes_count : 0;

    $Result = $likes + ( $comments * 1.2 );

  return $Result;
}`
```

Comment: try to use DB::raw sql query ... I'm not sure how to write the query though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fast solution (in terms of implementation) is to use `oderByRaw()`:

```php
$Posts->orderByRaw("
    (
        select count(*)
        from likes
        where likes.post_id = posts.id
    ) + (
        select count(*)
        from comments
        where comments.post_id = posts.id
    ) * 1.2 DESC
");
```

This however will be very slow if your `posts` table is huge. You could try to create a query with two joins and two aggregates, but that will not change much. It doesn't matter that you want to fetch only 5 rows - You will need to calculate the "popularity" for every post int the DB every time.

So if the performance is an issue, you can create three new "cache" columns in your `posts` table:

- `likes_count`
- `comments_count`
- `popularity`

with an index for the `popularity` column.

Every time you insert or delete a comment or a like, you will also need to update the related post. I would probably do that with triggers.

Having that, you can just use `orderBy('popularity', 'DESC')`.

You can also create a new table (`post_popularity`) with the columns `post_id, comments_count, likes_count, popularity` in order to phisicaly  separate the cached data. But then you would need a join:

```php
$Posts->join('post_popularity as pp', 'pp.post.id', '=', 'posts.id')
      ->orderBy(pp.popularity, 'DESC');
```

Comment: Hey. I believe it will be the best way to add likes_count, comments_count and popularity_count to database. It will have the best performance , and will be much faster. It shouldn't take much time to update it everytime someone comment or like post. In the future( depends on how much people will use the website ) I will have to use SOLR or ElasticSearch probably.

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

You should sort data before getting it:

```
$Posts->orderBy('popularity_count')->paginate(5);
```

When you use `sortBy()` after `paginate()`, you're only sorting collection of 5 items.

Comment: That's the thing, that I don't have popularity_count column in my database, so I can't use orderBy

Comment: Why do you use it in `sortBy()` then? And how do you count popularity?

Comment: I made a mistake with sortBy, and realized it just know. I have function PopularityCount and getPopularityCountAttribute which counts it. It works corectly

Comment: Please post the function. Also, if you explain relationship between `Posts` and some other model (with `popularity`), I'm sure we'll be able to help you.

Comment: I have updated my original post with popularityCount method